# Wordpress syntax highlighting

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I recently switched my blog from joomla to wordpress and i'm having problems when posting code snippets.

The editor seems to remove some of the characters when i save my posts.

I am using a plugin that i got from this link: [http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter)

Example:

```
<pre class="brush: javascript">;
var window.onload = function() {
    alert("Loading is complete");
};
</pre>
```

Is formatted to:

```
<pre>;
var window.onload = function() {
    alert("Loading is complete");
};
</pre>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on WordPress.com, I believe you should be using a shortcode like so: http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

If you're on self-hosted WordPress and using the WordPress plugin Syntax Highlighter (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntax-highlighter/), again I think the correct way to insert code is by wrapping it in a shortcode. So instead of < pre > you would use:

```
[javascript]
// your code here
[/javascript]
```

If neither of these sounds like an ideal solution (or works) there are a bunch of other syntax highlighter plugins for self-hosted WordPress that might be better: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=syntax+highlighter

Hope this helps - best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Michelle.
This actually works for me.

```
[sourcecode language='javascript']
    //Replace 'javascript' by the corresponding language
    //Your code goes here
[/sourcecode]
```

It will work on save or update for hosted and non hosted sites.
[Example](http://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/angularjs-your-first-hello-world-tutorial/).

To apply it to your text, you just have to switch to the 'Text' visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your pages will load faster if you do the syntax highlighting before posting, using pygmentize: http://permafrostcodingstudio.com/articles/syntax-highlighting-in-posts/

It's a little more complicated, but worth being able to disable a plugin.  Wordpress will run faster and be more secure with fewer plugins installed.